# Getting error when using SqlCommand

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting an error when I use `SqlCommand` in the code below, please advise.

```
try
{
    sqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new sqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bazy;Integrated Security=true ");

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select pass from Users where user1='" + user + "'", sqlConnection1);
    SqlDataReader sdr;

    sqlConnection1.open();

    sdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if (sdr.GetString(0) == tBox_oldPassword.Text)
    {
        cmd1.CommandText = "update Users set Pass='" + tBox_newPassword.Text + "' where User1='" + tBox_userName.Text + "'";
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ادخل كلمة السر الحالية.");
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please specify wich error you get (Message, Type, InnerExceptions) and on the precise line. "It is not working" has never been enough information for debugging.

Comment: Please don’t post screenshots. Post the text of the error message in the question itself. Thank you.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Unrelated tips: `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` are all `IDisposable` so should be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Ah. You need to give use the source code for `sqlConnection`, which is a class in your namespace, not Microsoft's `SqlConnection`. I had assumed it was just a formatting/typo mistake but the exception message shows that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem like you mistype'd `SqlConnection` as `sqlConnection` and then let Visual Studio (or possibly ReSharper, as it tends to use `throw new NotImplementedException();` as the body of methods it generates, and I'm unsure if that's VS' default behavior) automatically implement the class for you, with the constructor, or `open` method, throwing `NotImplementedException` as it has not been implemented by you.

Change

```
sqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new sqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bazy;Integrated Security=true ");
```

to

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Bazy;Integrated Security=true ");
```

and look into removing the `sqlConnection` class you've mistakenly added.

Comment: A good guess, but at bare minimum the `sqlConnection` class implements `SqlConnection` due to the use. If this *was* as you say it is, it would throw on `sqlConnection1.open()`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto That's a good point, looking at the error more closely, it looks like it's actually an unimplemented implicit conversion operator, likely to `SqlConnection`. This would explain why it can compile, as it does technically have an implicit conversion to `SqlConnection`, but it fails immediately when attempting to do so at run time. I'm curious as to _how_ this actually happened, and I suspect letting tools try to implement things is the culprit.